# Can an abstract method in Java have a default behavior even if it is overridden?

Tags: java

Maybe the approach is wrong. My idea is the following:

```
public abstract AbstractParser<T extends Value> {
  T value;

  //want to do something like
  public abstract void parseSomething(Model model) {
    value = (T) model.getValue()
  }
}
```

And then I want every subclass to override parseSomething without losing that default behavior. So when a children overrides parseSomething, it will have in **value** the correct implementation of it.

```
public ConcreteParser extends AbstractParser<ConcreteValue> {
  //now in Value I have a ConcreteValue to access

  @Override
  public void parseSomething(Model model) {
    //here I want to do stuff with value without having to do:
    value = (ConcreteValue) model.getValue();
    //in every implementation I create
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first that is missing, you'll need a `Class<T>` for the cast to `T` (Type erasure). (If Model is not parametrisable.)

For the problem there is a fine solution, with

- a final, non-overridable, public API *service* method - `parseSomething`;
- an internal, protected, *request* implementation method that should be overriden - onParseSomething.

The overridable method is called in the final public method and can have more parameters, like the value. The method could be `abstract`.

So:

```
public abstract AbstractParser<T extends Value> {
  private final Class<T> valueType;
  protected T value;

  protected AbstractParser(Class<T> valueType) {
    this.valueType = valueType;
  }

  // Class users will call this method
  public final void parseSomething(Model model) {
    value = valueType.cast(model.getValue());
    onParseSomething(model, value);
  }

  // Class implementors will override/implement this method
  protected void onParseSomething(Model model, T value) {
  }
}


public ConcreteParser extends AbstractParser<ConcreteValue> {

  public ConcreteParser() {
      super(ConcreteValue.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void onParseSomething(Model model, ConcreteValue value) {
  }
}
```

Comment: That's architecturally more complex then it should be, while also adding a redundant protected method, imho. Generics are the way to go.

Comment: @LppEdd Mind elaborating? It's hardly any more complex while also than using a getter; it's a simple [template method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). This solution injects the dependency into the behavior, which is more sturdy than having the behavior manually obtain those required entities themselves. Using a getter needlessly exposes the underlying property, which can cause problems later down the line.

Comment: @VinceEmigh see my answer below for details

Comment: @LppEdd I saw your answer. It has it's downfalls. [It's not object oriented](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/358612/139941); its procedural. It differs, and from experience, your solution has more downsides.

Comment: @LppEdd I've linked a related post. Objects should be interacted with via their behaviors, not their properties.

Comment: @VinceEmigh look, this answer is doing exactly the same thing mine is doing. With the added compexity of having a Class<T> injected and one more method. Plus the manual cast

Comment: @LppEdd No it's not.. If you'd like to discuss this further, create a chat. Otherwise, you should look into design, as it plays a huge role in software development. Just because two programs produce the same output does not mean they're the same - it may be easier to maintain and/or scale up one of the programs, while the other program is monolithic.

Comment: He means procedural because you're exposing all of your data members and not encapsulating/hiding things that don't need to be exposed, I believe @LppEdd

Comment: @VinceEmigh The point is "encapsulating" that method is not necessary, since the sub-class  will always receive the correct type using generics. There is no point in having that method final, if not for granting that the "value" property is assigned before use. But that's another story. Then I'd just rewrite the class using constructor injection for the "value"

Comment: @LppEdd "encapsulating is not necessary" - Encapsulation is a benefit, not a requirement in which you ask "is it really necessary?". It's something you aim for, not something you ask "is it needed?". If you want to continue this, feel free to create a chat.

Comment: @VinceEmigh as I wrote, if we really wanted to change the design, we could choose to inject the value via constructor, and make the class(+subclasses) immutable. Subclasses would just have to override the abstract method and use the final, already initialized, value. That's all. No need for compexity.

Comment: For other reasons I didn't comment in this question, this is the best approach for my situation. Thank you all for very clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this even extends to interfaces as of Java 8:

```
public interface IExample {

    default public String test() {
        return " world!";
    }

}

public class Example implements IExample {

    @Override
    public String test() {
        return "Hello " + IExample.super.test();
    }

}
```

For referencing super methods of parent interfaces, you must also include the class name before `super`. The end result:

```
System.out.println(new Example().test());
//Hello world!
```

Semantically, if you wanted to protect the functionality of a specific parent method, and have the subclasses define only a subset of the behavior, consider using a public facing method, and a protected method for defining that subset of behavior:

```
public abstract class AbstractParser<T extends Value> {

    protected T value;

    //final, cannot be overridden
    public final void parseSomething(Model model) {
        this.value = (T) model.getValue();
        this.continueParsing();
    }

    protected abstract void continueParsing();

}

public class ConcreteParser extends AbstractParser<ConcreteValue> {
    @Override
    protected void continueParsing() {
        //invoked after the value `T` is set by the public method
        //references to `this.value` will be of type `T` or in this case, `ConcreteValue`
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer. That is what he is looking for, I think.

Comment: Hm, even beyond that it seems like he wants a way to guarantee a subclass doesn't modify the behavior of the method. In which case I have yet another answer not listed here, sec...

Comment: "it will have in value the correct implementation of it". He just want the correctly casted type :)

Comment: Also, casting like that seems like abusing runtime. Compile time guarantees are always better.

Comment: I agree, however just continuing based off OP's example. In some ways you could probably argue that a class cast here would be an appropriate error to throw (since the subclass would be used incorrectly due to programmer error, and in non-generic form would do exactly the same). Overall I don't prefer a blind cast though.

Comment: Could you give your opinion on the upvoded answer's comments? I don't know if I'm going crazy or what.

Comment: The difference between your answers is the abstraction of the `public`/`protected` methods (in order to encapsulate the subclass behavior). Otherwise they're the same in my eyes, though I do agree the `Class<T>` is an ugly param since you can simply `(T)` and it will be the same operation essentially.

Comment: The point is "encapsulating" that method is not necessary, since the sub-class will always receive the correct type using generics. There is no point in having that method final, if not for granting that the "value" property is assigned. But that's another story

Comment: It depends on the context, if you have more complex behavior in the parent method this design can be very ideal. Yours is acceptable for a simpler case but becomes less maintainable if you want to separate distinct parts of the class' behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for can be accomplished via generics only.

The `Model` class could be parameterized:

```
class Model<T> {
   ...
   T getValue();
   ...
}
```

Then the `AbstractParser` class could be rewritten as:

```
abstract class AbstractParser<T> {
   T value;

   public abstract void parseSomething(final Model<T> model) {
      this.value = model.getValue();
   }
}
```

Since the garantee of having `value` initialized before usage is addressed, then the class could be rewritten to be immutable, with constructor injection.

```
abstract class AbstractParser<T> {
   final T value;

   AbstractParser(final Model<T> model) {
      this.value = model.getValue();
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna do it for you:

```
public ConcreteParser extends AbstractParser<ConcreteValue> {

 @Override
 public void parseSomething(Model model) {
   if(!(model instanceOf ConcreteValue)) // to ensure safety
      return;
   //do what ever you like first, this.value is null by far if 
   //this method is getting called the 1st time

   super.parseSomething(model);

   // now you can use value as you like from here on. 
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't guarantee the correctness of the type returned by model#getValue

Comment: @LppEdd I have modified my answer according to your comments.